# Convert video from .mp4 to .ogg

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using `ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers` . I need to convert a file .mp4, to .ogg format. I am on Mac OS X, and I have tried this so far:

```
ffmpeg -i sample_mpeg4.mp4 -acodec vorbis -vcodec libtheora -f ogg output.ogv
```

I am getting: `Unknown encoder 'libtheora'`

```
ffmpeg -i sample_mpeg4.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -vcodec --enable-libtheora output.ogv
```

I am getting: `Unknown encoder '--enable-libtheora'`

```
ffmpeg -i sample_mpeg4.mp4 -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libtheora -f ogv output.ogv
```

I am getting:

```
[NULL @ 0x7f81bb00f800] Requested output format 'ogv' is not a suitable output format
output.ogv: Invalid argument
```

`ffmpegtheora` is not an option as it can not be install on the server.

Comment: What about `ffmpeg -i file.mp4 file.ogg`? This works on my Debian wheezy box, not sure about Mac OS X.

Comment: Nope. It does not work

Comment: Then it's an OSX-specific problem. You most probably don't have the required codecs.

Comment: In the future, when asking FFmpeg questions, please include the full, uncut command output, not just the error messages you think are relevant.

Answer (score 12):

Your FFmpeg version is missing the required encoders, `libtheora` for Theora video and `libvorbis` for Vorbis audio.

You can only add these encoders by either

- compiling them with FFmpeg, or
- installing an executable that bundles them already.

For you the easiest choice would be to download a static version from [the FFmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). They all come with `libtheora` and `libvorbis`, regardless of the operating system they were built for.

What you then need to do is extract the download archive and simply run the `ffmpeg` binary that was included. The correct syntax would be:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis out.ogv
```

If you want to change the quality for either audio or video, you can change the bit rate, e.g. with `-b:v 1M` or `-b:a 192k`. Play with those values and use a higher or lower bitrate depending on the quality or file size constraints you have.

You can also use VBR (constant quality) with `-q:v`, where values range from 0 to 10 (higher is better), with 7 being recommended. The audio quality can be set with `-q:a`, again with values from 0 to 10, where 4 is recommended and corresponds to roughly 128 kBit/s.

<sub>Note that `--enable-libtheora` is a configuration option and doesn't work when calling `ffmpeg`.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

Use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager

Install Homebrew in command line

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install ffmpeg with libtheora support

```
$ brew install ffmpeg --with-theora --with-libvorbis
```

Other options are listed here

```
$ brew options ffmpeg
```

Hope it helps others or future me ;)

Comment: You might also need `--with-libvorbis`, like this: `brew install ffmpeg --with-theora --with-libvorbis`

Comment: You can also use `reinstall` brew reinstall ffmpeg --with-theora --with-libvorbis

Answer (score 0):

--enable-libtheora should be used when building ffmpeg from source, not while trying to run the program. You should try rebuilding ffmpeg (using [the latest source of course](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) ) and adding support for libtheora during configure (./configure --enable-libtheora etc....)

If you need help on building from source, there's lots of stuff on google, but it boils down (for you) enabling the libraries you need, you can see [here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/31) and _http://jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html for starters.

Comment: There's usually no need to build from source, as it can be quite a chore on OS X. Package managers such as Homebrew simplify this task, but the OP may as well just use a static build from the FFmpeg download page.